# Says I don't have numpy, then it says it is already installed

Tags: python, numpy

I am having issues with the numpy library. I am trying to code a webcam using the opencv library, but I am getting this issue:

```
OpenCV bindings requires "numpy" package.
Install it via command:
    pip install numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/security-camera/take_picture.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import numpy.core.multiarray
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core.multiarray'
```

When I try to install numpy using pip, I get this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/security-camera $ python3 -m pip install numpy
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.19.5)
```

It says I already have the numpy library, even though when I run it says to install it. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like `pip` is referencing a different pip than the one you installed numpy on. Are you using a virtual environment or do you have multiple versions of python installed?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve this issue: I was getting an issue with numpy earlier and was trying to reinstall it, so I deleted the numpy folder in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, then I tried to install it again but it did not work. Then I got this issue. There are actually two numpy folders in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, so when I deleted the one with the python files in it, and imported numpy in the python program, it says numpy did not exist, but when I tried to reinstall numpy with pip, it said it already existed because it looked at the other folder. So what I had to do was delete the other folder in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, and then reinstalling numpy worked.